# Why does switching to the tty give me a blank screen?

Tags: command-line, virtual-console

After booting to the GUI in 12.04, I attempt to move to the virtual terminal (or shell, or tty) via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> (<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd>), and the screen remains blank. I have tried all 6 tty instances and the results are the same. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> brings me back to the GUI without a problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: This occurs often together with being unable to see Grub of the boot splash. Can you see those?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is usually caused because the *graphical* text-mode resolution set at boot up is not compatible with your video card. The solution is to switch to true text-mode by configuring Grub appropriately:

1. Open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Paste the below, and enter your password when asked:

   ```
   sudo sed -i -e 's/#GRUB_TERMINAL/GRUB_TERMINAL/g' /etc/default/grub
   ```
3. Then type `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot and the virtual terminals should now work.

Comment: That did it, thanks! It made the text a bit bigger than I would like once it reset to default. I opened the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file to edit the text size and the first line states "do not edit". Suppose that's a question for another day though. Thanks for the help

Comment: Also works for me in 14.04.... great tip.

Comment: Indeed, have some karma.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help with my graphic-driver issues (I need the X server down to install proper drivers, but the lack of drivers prevents me from getting a working command-line with `ctrl-alt-F1`).

Comment: This thing left my grub to black & white.

Comment: CAREFUL, this thing has completely messed up my grub, I don't see a boot menu anymore. (Ubuntu 15.04)

Comment: @izx so this command opens `/etc/default/grub` and changes the line `#GRUB_TERMINAL` to `#GRUB_TERMINAL/g` right? I'm asking this just to know how to undo if anything goes wrong

Comment: @MinaMichael No. It changes `#GRUB_TERMINAL` to `GRUB_TERMINAL`. The slash ends the regular expression, and the g is the global-modifier that sais: replace ALL matches.

Comment: Doesn't work on 14.0.4 for me

Comment: +1.  This also solves a somewhat different problem: After the 16.04 upgrade I was actually able to see the virtual terminals `hostname login:` prompts but there was no input (keyboard echo) in them so I couldn't login.  Uncommenting the `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` line followed by `sudo update-grub` solved this.

Comment: Did not work for me in 14.014, and now when I reboot, I get 'error: no video mode activated.' Can someone please tell me how to undo whatever I just did?

Comment: @neuronet, Mount the drive on another machine, chroot to the rootfs, and regenerate/update your grub config.

Comment: Hey @izx, I followed your steps. But the problem hasn't been solved yet. I got a black and white grub. But the terminals are black. actually, whenever the swap fills up, be it even a byte. My terminals go black. I am able to type on them. I just did chvt 2 and logged in to that blcak terminal and executed sudo reboot and it worked. The problem is with the display only. My problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/876982/virtual-consoles-tty1-tty6-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Grub file states  # Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console  Why would disabling graphical terminal fix this issue? For Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This worked for me (kubuntu 16.04), but @MinaMichael s answer of setting `GRUB_GFXMODE=auto` worked better because it didn't change my grub menus.

Answer (score 15):

What fixed this for me was adding `nomodeset` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in the `/etc/default/grub` file. Here's how:

1. Type in terminal: `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Search for this line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

   So for example if you have:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
   ```

   change it to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1 nomodeset"
   ```
3. After you finish, update grub (`sudo update-grub`) and reboot (`sudo reboot`) for the changes to take effect.

**Optional**: You could add `nomodeset vga=xxx` (not just `nomodeset`), the xxx is a VESA screen code that best matches your screen resolution. Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Linux_video_mode_numbers).

Comment: Worked for me. Be sure to read the last paragraph above, about running `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes.

Comment: Worked for me on 14.0.4

Comment: When I do this with 14.04 and some Hardware enabling stack whatever this works technically, but graphical desktop is not booted into nor does startx work. But the terminal is back.

Comment: For me  On Ubuntu 16.04 this caused my HDMI-VGA monitor to completely stop working.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you can undo it from tty. I hope it wasn't too much trouble

Comment: How does this interact with having `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` set to something?

Comment: I didn't know but I found [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/575651/what-is-the-difference-between-grub-cmdline-linux-and-grub-cmdline-linux-default). suchen bevor Sie fragen @einpoklum

Answer (score 7):

This is for newer version of Ubuntu:

1. Edit the GRUB configuration file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Locate the line

   ```
   #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
   ```

   change it to

   ```
   GRUB_GFXMODE=auto
   ```

   and save the file.
3. Then update grub

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04.5 I installed a program that caused a 4.x kernel to be installed. Previously I had a 3.x kernel. This answer is what fixed this issue of blank ttys for me on an Asus Zenbook UX303LN.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at my question at https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/643882, with regards to virtual terminal not functioning on Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad T400.

The solution i presented is geared towards user with Hybrid Graphics Card, in particular, AMD/ATI graphics card and Intel integrated graphics card. For me, disabling the intel graphics card and enabling the opensource ATI/AMD radeon module helps in my case.

If you are using a old Radeon graphics card like mine (Radeon HD 3450/3470), now you can switch between virtual terminal and graphical desktop with ease to troubleshoot potential issues.

If adding `blacklist intel_graphics_card` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and running

```
sudo depmod -a
```

still doesn't work due to linux kernel or other dependencies, you are advised to add `modprobe.blacklist=<module_name>` to `/etc/default/grub` like the following example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash crashkernel=384M-:128M radeon.dpm=1  modprobe.blacklist=i915"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to shut down the graphics driver after you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> before you try to install the Nvidia driver

As in `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop`

Comment: "before you try to install the Nvidia driver" - I'm not sure what you mean by that. The question doesn't mention anything about Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 with 2560x1440 screen:

- open grub configuration file in editor: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- uncomment GFXMODE and set your exact resolution -> change`#GRUB_GFXMODE` to`GRUB_GFXMODE=2560x1440`
- add line `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep`
- Add remove `splash` and add `nosplash noplymouth nomodeset` to your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. After cahnges mine looks like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nosplash noplymouth intel_idle.max_cstate=1 nomodeset"`
- save the file
- update grub `sudo update-grub`
- reboot
- use Ctlr+Alt+F2 to switch immediately after boot