# On Ubuntu 16.04, cannot enter CMD mode by CTRL+ALT+F1

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia

First of all, sorry about the "unprofessional way" of asking this question on this website. I'll keep editing and updating this description.

I'm a newcomer to Ubuntu, so my question might be a bit naive. I'll stay with my computer for the entire day and watch the notification from this website. Let me know if you want any other information (and best to tell me HOWTO, I appreciate it).

What I am doing is I want to install a second system on my Laptop, it was with Win10, now it's Win10 + Ubuntu 16.04. After a painful day I success, so I then want to install the close-sourced NVIDIA driver for it. But I failed for more than 10 times and everytime I need to reinstall my Ubuntu...

Many tutorials and blogs points out I need to blacklist the default nouveau driver, and shutdown the X server to install the NVIDIA driver. However, if I do so:

(1) After I blacklist the default driver, I basically can never return to my GUI after a reboot. I can see the grub page and select Ubuntu, then all I have is a blank/black screen.

(2) If I shutdown the X server, I immediately enter a black screen. Every blog posts told me to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, but I tried <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd> there but nothing happens.

(3) When I was on my Ubuntu desktop, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, my mouse gone but the GUI left (however, even with keyboard I cannot type anything, looks like a frozen computer.) and I cannot do anything with it. But if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, my mouse comes back and everything is fine.

Please please let me know if you want any other information from me.
BTW, I have read at least 5 posts about this issue and tried every upvoted answer on ASKUBUNTU and none of them can help with my case.

For example,

[CTRL + ALT + F1 show nothing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256838/ctrl-alt-f1-show-nothing)

[Why does switching to the tty give me a blank screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162535/why-does-switching-to-the-tty-give-me-a-blank-screen)

UPDATE 1:

After shutting down the X server, the system is still running but with a black screen, as I can ssh to it from another computer.
I've also tried to use ssh to complete the task but that points out why I am asking this question. I blacklist the nouveau driver, then I reboot. And after I select Ubuntu from GRUB, I just have a black screen. I cannot ssh to it. And I cannot use tty by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. If I can enter the CMD mode then the problem can be solved.

Comment: Are you at all able to work on a GUI? You can always try and use propriety drivers from Nvidia. What GPU are you using?

Comment: @KrisStadler GTX 1070 on notebook. My GUI is fine with the default driver nouveau.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way: install Ubuntu again, open the 'software updater' (update-manager) and wait till it is finished loading, then ignore the outcome it shows, and click on 'settings' and go to the tab 'additional drivers'. There you will see the Nvidia driver appear. That's what i do to install them. After that you can choose to install Nvidia Settings to set your desktop colors and gamma setting to your liking. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but how comes I cannot activate virtual terminals, namely, tty1 to tty6.