# How to get virtual console when ALT+CTRL+F1-F6 not working?

Tags: java

I wanted to install JRE latest. When I had Java (TM)...
So I purged java*

next time, I restart the system, I get a login screen. but after passwd given, it says `failed to load session ubuntu`.

I looked at the suggestions to this problem...in many places, first it requires a virtual console using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> (keys). But I only get a black screen with nothing on it.
Hence my question.

Any help would be much much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any graphics card? (if yes) have you installed its driver properly?

Comment: the graphics card is in-built. its an i7 desktop. installed  64 bit ubuntu few weeks ago.

Comment: You can see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/162596/127327)

Comment: Can you use the "Recovery mode" to re-install java?

Comment: Thanks. I do not get a terminal using ALT+CTRL+T. Hence I can not proceed with the following. Yet to find a way to get a terminal.

Comment: Dear Jobin, how do I go to the recovery mode?