# (noob) driver for GTX 970 install issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

Sorry, it's my first time on a Linux system and I'm totally lost.

I want to install the NVidia driver because I'm stuck with a 1024 x 768 resolution and I think my GPU doesn't work properly with the default graphic driver (Nouveau?)....

So I tried to install the NVidia driver 352.21;
apparently I need to go in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>,   but when I try this, I get a black screen and nothing else unless I return in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

I really don't want to damage something so I hope someone have a solution...

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance

Comment: I found something who fixed the black screen when switching to tty, now I can use it, nice. But still that would be nice if someone can explain me how to do with the driver... thanks.
Solution for the blackscreen thing :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/162535/why-does-switching-to-the-tty-give-me-a-blank-screen

Comment: I find how to instal the nvidia driver with this link :
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/06/install-nvidia-352-21-ubuntu-1404/

I hope that will be useful for someone else, bye

Comment: how are you trying to install it? From Ubuntu deault repository or using `.run` file from Nvidia?

Comment: for the latest nvidia cards I recommend directly downloaded video driver. You can follow my complete tutorial [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-from-the-run-file/423619#423619)

Comment: Installing drivers from .run files are WRONG! System will not boot after first kernel upgrade. And you blacklist nouveau, so nothing will work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Install the driver this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```