# Grub is black/white , but I want my old Grub back :)

Tags: grub2, virtual-terminal

I had an blank screen on the terminal-mode, via Ctrl-Alt-F1 (F1 - 6), on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I followed the steps of izx and it worked, thx for that :) [link to izx's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/162596/568839)

but now I have a black/white grub, which I don't like, so I was wondering if somebody can help me get my old grub back like this example from google:

[image: (like this one)]

And this,is how my GRUB looks right now:

[image]

I tried to edit my GRUB with the "grub customizer", but the resolution and colors don't change.

btw I'm relatively new to linux/Ubuntu :D

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do something to install a new grub version on your computer? I also use 16.04 gut when I run `grub-install --version` I get
`grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.1` What I see on your screen looks like a quite old version. Also your linux kernel image is quite old. What do you get when you type `lsb_release -a` and `uname -r` in your terminal?

Comment: grub-install only adds BIOS/UEFI-executable code the the hard drive, and has nothing to do with the configuration of GRUB. That configuration lies in /boot/grub/grub.cfg, which gets loaded everytime the computer boots up. There's something in there that changes GRUB to black/white. IDK what it is, but you can change it automatically with the solution I mentioned below. In other words, if your computer is booting just fine, there's no reason to mess with grub-install.

Comment: the picture of that GRUB is from google, it's just an example how it looked on my system before :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no way to do so, without completely reverting izx's solution. Basically, what has happened is GRUB is now in a safe mode of sorts. It no longer shows graphics that might be too complicated, since that might cause issues.

To undue this solution (and maybe try another), you could use `sudo sed -i -e 's/GRUB_TERMINAL/#GRUB_TERMINAL/g' /etc/default/grub ; sudo update-grub`
That will allow you to get a pretty grub once again. However, if you are having trouble with TTY1-6, and izx's solution has helped, it might just be worth it to keep GRUB plain-looking.

Comment: thx for your help, it worked :) And now, somehow the terminal-mode is working too :D

Answer (score 0):

Install `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text` with the command

```
sudo apt install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
```

and then make this the default for `text.plymouth` entry using this command

sudo update-alternatives --config text.plymouth

Select the entry which says `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth` by pressing the number beside this entry and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then use this command `sudo update-initramfs -u -v` and reboot to see changes.