# Unable to access any tty terminal

Tags: tty

I log on to the GUI. I am unable to access terminals 1,2,3,5,6 using ctrl-alt-Fx. 
The only terminal I CAN access is tty4 ( ctrl alt F4). When I do, I can access it as normal, but am unable to revert back to gui terminal ( F7 ). 
Pressing ctrl alt Fx results in special charactees like ~,^,@ etc. Being printed. 
If I press ctrl alt f9 f10 or f11 in tty4, it hangs the pc, leaving me unable to type.

In gui, when i do sudo service tty1 restart, it gives me an error saying service tty1 is not running.

I have no clue how to fix this. Can someone pls help me figure out what to do...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does switching to the tty give me a blank screen?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162535/why-does-switching-to-the-tty-give-me-a-blank-screen)