# Ctrl+Alt+F1 stopped working in 16.04.LTS

Tags: 16.04, login, tty

In older versions of Ubuntu I used to be able to get a character based login screen by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>f1</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>...).

After I upgraded to 16.04 LTS this no longer works. All I get when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>f1</kbd> is a dark, blank screen. (Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> to switch back to the graphical user interface works.)

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

I was trying to experiment with @sudodus' comment below, but before I got that far, I discovered some strange behaviour.

1. Sometimes I *can* get the consoles to work, but not always.
2. Sometimes the consoles display a login prompt, but do not accept any input.
3. Sometimes the computer locks completely when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. (I can't event ssh to the computer from another computer.)

Perhaps what I really need is a fresh install... Sigh! :-(

**EDIT**

I just updated my computer from 4GB to 8GB of RAM. This solved the problem. (Confusing, I think; but I'm happy now.)

Comment: It works for me in 16.04.1 LTS. Maybe there is some problem with the graphics. What happens if you boot with the boot option nomodeset, or with GRUB_TERMINAL=console via '/etc7default/grub' and 'sudo update-grub'. See this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup

Comment: For reference, possibly a duplicate of (for example): http://askubuntu.com/questions/162535/why-does-switching-to-the-tty-give-me-a-blank-screen  . It seems to work for me (for now) by setting both  `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` and `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`

Comment: see also (unrelated, but similar search terms might lead one to the wrong question) https://askubuntu.com/questions/979027/how-do-i-switch-between-console-mode-and-gui-in-17-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the **EDIT** in my post, the problem was solved by increasing the amount of memory in the computer.

Answer (score -2):

sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart working by me.