# How to switch between console mode and GUI in 17.10 in X.Org mode?

Tags: 17.10, gdm, virtual-console

This is related to this question about [How to switch between console mode and GUI in 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979027/how-to-switch-between-console-mode-and-gui-in-17-10). I tried the highly-upvoted answer, which sounds like it is correct, but it does not work for me.

I am currently running Ubuntu 17.10 with the X.Org session (due to sometimes relying on X-tools, like x2x). This is in contrast to the OP in the other question, who seems to run the default Wayland session.

When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> on this machine, not a lot happens. The desktop freezes, the mouse vanishes, and, most importantly, I don't get a virtual terminal. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> returns me successfully to my running session.

[In the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/979029/17342), they cite the release notes, which state that

> - GDM has replaced LightDM as the default display manager. The login screen now uses virtual terminal 1 instead of virtual terminal 7.

In addition they note that the currently running session moved to tty2 and unused virtual terminals are available after that.

So, why does this work under Wayland, but only partially with the fallback X.Org session? After all, the move of the currently running session to tty2 seems to have worked. But how do I get to a virtual console?

Comment: ^In case that doesn't help, add the output of `systemctl status getty@tty3.service` to your post.

Comment: @muru One of the answers in the linked question indeed solved it (https://askubuntu.com/a/954554/17342).