# How do I access a console TTY on a MacBook?

Tags: tty, macbook-pro

I've got a MacBook that I was finally able to get Ubuntu running on and then I upgraded to 17.10 and it choked again. It's booting to a login screen, but when I log in I get a black screen.

I'd like to hop over to TTY 2 and log in at a terminal prompt but <kbd>crtl</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>crtl</kbd>-<kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> doesn't do anything. I read somewhere that I have to hit fn first, but that also has no effect.

Reading [How do I switch between console mode and GUI in 17.10 and newer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979027) clued me into part of my problem: TTY1 and TTY2 are spoken for in 17.10. But I'm still not clear on the keyboard sequence to shift between TTYs.

How do I get to a console TTY on a MacBook Pro keyboard?

Comment: Did you try all Ctl+Alt+F1 to F6 combinations?

Comment: I banged around and got to TTY3 but I don't know what worked. I think it was fn-crtl-opt-F3 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I switch between console mode and GUI in 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979027/how-do-i-switch-between-console-mode-and-gui-in-17-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I needed <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Opt</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

One could also try <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>⇠</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>⇢</kbd>

Comment: @matigo I meant ctrl not cmd

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an external keyboard that has Windows/Mac mode to choose from, make sure you choose the Windows mode, as Linux and Windows share the same keyboard layout. And then you can use the normal ways to enter a TTY.