# Steam on Ubuntu 18.04 refusing to start. Nvidia. "libGL error: failed to load driver"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, steam

I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux. I've been trying all day to find a fix for steam to work but I keep getting the same error. Steam refuses to start when I run it using the icon on the desktop or the icon in the applications menu. When I type

```
steam
```

into the terminal I get this error:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I haven't found a single thread with my problem, I keep finding people with AMD graphics cards that have driver issues but no luck with NVIDIA.

Comment: This is because Nvidia dropped support for 32 bits binaries, and Steam is 32 bits. I've posted the solution for it here https://askubuntu.com/a/1151546/453743

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. You can fix it by removing your NVIDIA drivers and install them from their website (that worked for me, because it seems to be a newer version[390.44 -> 390.77]). This has been tested only under Linux Mint 19, which based on Ubuntu 18.04 - theoretically it works under Ubuntu too.

1. Download the NVIDIA driver
2. Remove NVIDIA:

   ```
   sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-390 -y
   ```
3. Clean up:

   ```
   sudo apt autoremove -y
   ```
4. Log out!
5. Switch to console by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT+F3</kbd>
6. Log in...
7. Stop the display manager:

   ```
   sudo service gdm stop    #or lightdm
   ```
8. `cd Downloads` (or wherever it is)
9. Make the driver executable:

   ```
   chmod +x [driver package name]
   ```
10. Run and install it (let it fix xserver settings AND libs!!!!):

    ```
    ./[driver package name]
    ```
11. Enter: `reboot`
12. Should work now!

Comment: Hi @Simonmicro ! Console on tty1 and lightdm sound like 16.04. Could you please clarify if the instructions are for 16.04 or 18.04 or maybe work on both?

Comment: It a solution for Linux Mint 19 - based on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver ;)

Comment: At least 3. and 5. are different in Ubuntu 18.04, so maybe you could indicate that the procedure was only tested on Linux Mint 19.

Comment: Okay, according to https://askubuntu.com/questions/979027/how-do-i-switch-between-console-mode-and-gui-in-17-10-and-newer you will need to press CTRL + ALT + F3 / F4 to open the console. And you must run sudo service gdm stop to kill the display manager.