# Nvidia graphics card not found, system details shows NV126 instead of GeForce GTX 960

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics, ubuntu-drivers

I have been wrestling with this issue intensively for three days now, and several different tutorials and searches still haven't helped. In my system Details, the processor is correctly identified as Intel, but after *Graphics* it just says *NV126*. I have a GeForce GTX 960 graphics card installed. No applications utilize the GeForce GTX 960 when they are run.

During my last attempt, I completely reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04. Then I ran `ubuntu-drivers devices` which found my graphics card. After that I ran `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. Then I rebooted, checked in *Software & Updates* under the *Additional drivers* tab that the *nvidia-driver-390* option was selected instead of the *xserver-xorg-video-nouveau* option.

But still in my system Details it just says that graphics are NV126, and the graphics card doesn't work.

> What does NV126 mean? How can I get the system to use my graphics card?

[image: Screenshot of my system details]
<sup>**Screenshot of system details**</sup>

Answer (score 2):

According to [nouveau/CodeNames wiki](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames/) (freedesktop.org) NV126 is the codename for the GeForce GTX (950, 960) graphics card. This codename correctly matches your GeForce GTX 960 graphics card. *Settings* -> *Details* shows the graphics card's codename in your Ubuntu 18.04.

When you open Software & Updates and click the Additional Drivers tab, it starts searching for additional drivers and shows a screen like the below screenshot.

[image]

As you can see in the bottom left corner of the screenshot it says *No proprietary drivers are in use.* while it is searching for additional drivers. Give the application a minute or two to finish searching and it will display a list of installed graphics drivers. The graphics driver that is currently being used has the radio button to the left of it selected.

You can also install Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver (*nvidia-settings*) to show what graphics driver is currently being used. It does a better job of identifying the Nvidia graphics card model than the System Profiler hardware information application does.

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-settings
```

To open the NVIDIA X Server Settings application search for *nvidia* in the Dash and click on its icon.

Some applications require additional software to be installed to make optimal use of the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver. For example Blender's Cycles render engine requires *nvidia-cuda-toolkit*. The Compute Unified Device Architecture (CUDA) enables NVIDIA graphics processing units (GPUs) to be used for massively parallel general purpose computation.

Comment: **Thank you very much!** It's so frustrating that I never encountered these codenames before -.- _Could you help point me in a direction of a list of additional software like CUDA?_ Even if my GPU is properly installed, some software complain that "no compatible hardware was found" when I try to run them.

Comment: 1. Visit [this webpage](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cuda&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all) for Ubuntu 18.04. 2. [Steam on Ubuntu 18.04 refusing to start. Nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054596/steam-on-ubuntu-18-04-refusing-to-start-nvidia)