# Why can't I open mendeleydesktop from terminal?

Tags: command-line, mendeley

I installed mendeley desktop via [this link](https://www.mendeley.com/download-desktop/). It installed properly and works fine when I open it from the gui menu.

However, I can't run it from terminal:

```
kp@kk:~$ mendeleydesktop
mendeleydesktop: command not found
kp@kk:~$
```

I located the software

```
kp@kk:~$ locate mendeleydesktop |grep /home
/home/kp/.local/share/mendeleydesktop
/home/kp/.local/share/applications/mendeleydesktop.desktop
```

The first item above seems like a link to a different directory, but I'm confused because I can't actually locate this file.

```
kp@kk:~/.local/share$ ls -al mendeleydesktop 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kp kp 30 Nov 19 17:38 mendeleydesktop -> /app/extra/bin/mendeleydesktop
```

The second item is just a file:

```
kp@kk:~/.local/share/applications$ cat mendeleydesktop.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mendeley Desktop
GenericName=Research Paper Manager
Comment=Mendeley Desktop is software for managing and sharing research papers
Exec=/home/kp/.local/share/mendeleydesktop %f
Icon=mendeleydesktop
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Education;Literature;Qt;
X-SuSE-translate=false
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mendeley;application/pdf;text/x-bibtex;
X-Mendeley-Version=1
```

Any idea where I can find the executable? I just want to be able to type `mendeleydesktop` and get mendeley to open. This is the only piece of my workflow I can't control from the terminal. I assume if I find the right object I can just make a link in my bashrc file.

Comment: please check! what the output of `sudo apt-cache policy mendeleydesktop`? and the data directory should be on `/opt/mendeleydesktop` !!

Comment: Hi @abu-ahmedal-khatiri -- `sudo apt-cache policy mendeleydesktop` returns 
`N: Unable to locate package mendeleydesktop`, and I find no data in `/opt/mendeleydesktop`. The data I find in `/home/kp/.var/app/com.elsevier.MendeleyDesktop/data/data/Mendeley Ltd.`

Comment: probably it not completely installed, that's mean you don't have the repository of mendeley, that's should be like http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/g23SCRyYMz/ ,try to add the repository

Comment: to fix it, try to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mendeleydesktop` for reconfigure mendeley package to include the repository and data directory. when you type `locate mendeleydesktop` should be like http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cWJr5B8fsR/

Comment: Doesn't work for me. dpgk doesn't know what mendeleydesktop means. I'm not sure exactly how to add the repository. I searched around but couldn't find much

Answer (score 1):

You have provided `mendeleydesktop.desktop` file, where it says that your executable is

```
/home/kp/.local/share/mendeleydesktop %f
```

`%f` is a parameter and stands for file (look here https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables). So typing

```
/home/kp/.local/share/mendeleydesktop
```

should work for you.

For me typing just

```
mendeleydesktop
```

works as it executes `/usr/bin/mendeleydesktop`, and `/usr/bin` is in PATH. I believe it should be in your path, too. Try to type

```
/usr/bin/mendeleydesktop
```

If that does not work, check, which files are installed with mendeleydesktop package. Type

```
dpkg -L mendeleydesktop
```

You will see all files that are installed, and find the one that is executed.

Comment: When I try running the the executable `/home/kp/.local/share/mendeleydesktop` I find 
`bash: /home/kp/.local/share/mendeleydesktop: No such file or directory`, however it's definitely there. I see it when I navigate to the directory

Comment: any idea why the terminal doesn't understand the executable?

Comment: Try `ls -l /home/kp/.local/share/mendeleydesktop`. lt should find the file and write permissions for it. See it file is executable. You try this in a terminal windows in you XWindows session, right? You are not doing this in text mode (tty) terminal or on another computer via ssh, telnet,..?

Comment: That's correct, I'm in the standard xwindows session. Same thing: in the `/home/kp/.local/share` directory I see `mendeleydesktop`, but when I type `./mendeleydesktop` from that directory, I get `no such file or directory` in return. Oddly I also can't tab complete `mendeleydesktop`.

Comment: Check if the file has executable permission with `ls -l`. This is a wild guess, but try `bash /home/kp/.local/share/mendeleydesktop` or `chmod 755 /home/kp/.local/share/mendeleydesktop`, and then `./mendeleydesktop`.

Answer (score 0):

**I think your issue is not about .desktop file,** i also have

```
$ cat /home/praz/.local/share/applications/mendeleydesktop.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mendeley Desktop
GenericName=Research Paper Manager
Comment=Mendeley Desktop is software for managing and sharing research papers
Exec=/home/praz/.local/share/mendeleydesktop %f
Icon=mendeleydesktop
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Education;Literature;Qt;
X-SuSE-translate=false
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mendeley;application/pdf;text/x-bibtex;
X-Mendeley-Version=1
```

**The problem's** :

You need to switch from the standard text mode (tty) XWindows session to the default GNOME session (GDM)

try switch the [gdm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979027/how-do-i-switch-between-console-mode-and-gui-in-17-10-and-newer/979029#979029) using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to go back to GUI, or use a command `chvt 1`

after you switch back to GNOME, please check again the `mendeley` package using :

```
sudo apt-cache policy mendeleydesktop
```

and the output should be like :

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy mendeleydesktop
[sudo] password for praz: 
mendeleydesktop:
  Installed: 1.19.3
  Candidate: 1.19.3
  Version table:
 *** 1.19.3 500
        500 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**IF** you still don't have the `mendeley` Repository, try to run :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mendeleydesktop
```

for reconfigure mendeley package to include the `mendeley` repository and data directory of `mendeley` package, and check your `mendeley` package with type :

```
sudo dpkg -L mendeleydesktop
```

the output should be like :

```
...
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/mendeleydesktop
/opt
/opt/mendeleydesktop
/opt/mendeleydesktop/lib
/opt/mendeleydesktop/lib/cpp
/opt/mendeleydesktop/lib/cpp/libstdc++.so.6
/opt/mendeleydesktop/lib/qt
/opt/mendeleydesktop/lib/qt/libQt5Widgets.so.5
/opt/mendeleydesktop/lib/qt/libicudata.so.56
...
```

Hope this helps.