# Virtual consoles (tty1-tty6) not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: suspend, swap, tty, virtual-console

Mostly, when I open more than 1 instances of Android Studio, somethings must be getting swapped onto the SWAP memory.
Virtual consoles show erratic behavior when swap is used.

The tty1 to tty6 terminals show an old screen. I can't say blank screen because they display what was present last on them. For eg. before this problem occurs, I had switched to tty3 then all tty1 to tty6 show tty3.
This problem also occurs after resuming fromm a suspend.

An observation is that, when I type any command on the consoles, they are executed.
So, basically the problem is with displaying. The virtual consoles are functioning.

Please help!!!