# Why can I not use the virtual consoles on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, suspend, tty, virtual-console

I'm currently unable to use any of my virtual terminals on Ubuntu 16.04 (the ASCII consoles accessible with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F[1-6]</kbd> or `chvt`; that is, `/dev/tty[1-6]`), but only intermittently. When I first boot up, I can access and use them as usual with no problems. However, eventually, they become essentially frozen; there's some pattern associated with suspending the laptop, but not reliably reproducibly. I can switch to a different virtual terminal, and I see the contents of `/etc/issue` at the top with my login prompt, but am unable to login or execute any commands. Strangely enough, the `tty` displayed is whatever the last virtual terminal I was in prior to suspend (e.g. pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> does send me to the virtual console, but it states `ttyN` instead, where `N` is whichever `tty` I used last).

This has made me think the issue is with my video driver not drawing the `tty` screen after suspend, but [following the steps here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157111/why-are-my-virtual-consoles-completely-blank) has not solved my problem.

Things I have tried:

1. Setting `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in `/etc/default/grub` and running `update-grub`
2. Setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"` in `/etc/default/grub` (which breaks a bunch of other things in my graphical environment anyway)
3. Reconfiguring the console font and display with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`
4. Attempting to reset the consoles with `sudo dellocvt`

People with [NVIDIA video cards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157111/why-are-my-virtual-consoles-completely-blank) have reported similar problems, but I'm on a Thinkpad with an Intel graphics card, so that doesn't apply to me (although I've tried their solutions, unfortunately with no success). As mentioned I've tried [adjusting GRUB_TERMINAL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162535/why-does-switching-to-the-tty-give-me-a-blank-screen) similarly without solving the issue.

My system:

```
Hardware: Lenovo Thinkpad X1 generation 3
$ lsb_release -d: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
$ uname -ri: 4.4.0-62-generic x86_64
$ lspci | grep VGA: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
Kernel driver: i915
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did figure this out, but it's fixed as of upgrading to 18.04 (bionic). Hope that helps some of you :)